# Copy and paste Typo3 Sites between 2 backends

Tags: typo3, backend, content-management-system

I am managing around 12 TYPO3 backends with almost similar content. Is it possible to copy and paste a created site between independent backends? Right now I'm creating by hand 12 sites with the same content. There has to be an easier way.

Well, there is not much I could try. Within TYPO3 I don't see any option to export/import sites from other backends.

Comment: Why do you have 12 websites with the same content? Is there any reason to have 12 TYPO3 backends instead of maybe one with 12 domains?

Comment: Thats not the discussion here. Still waiting for an answer how to copy/paste from one backend to another backend.

Comment: You got the answer. Use the extension impexp to export your pages and import them afterwards. You can do this as well for a single page.

Comment: I see export/import on instance 1. But on instance 2 i only see "export". So how do i import something in instance 2?

Comment: You should take a look into the docs: https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-impexp/main/en-us/

Answer (score 2):

First of all you should merge those 12 sites into one backend with multiple root sites and trees. Then you can easily handle different domains and/or languages via the site configurations for those roots.

Of course you can then make use of shared sys_folder pages that contain the content elements, that should be available for multiple sites. To make them available for a specific site, you can use references then.

Comment: i dont want to merge 12 site. I simply want to copy one single page from my backend and paste to another backend.

Comment: But this would be the easier way, you asked for. If you do not *want* it in that easier way, it's to you...

Comment: The point is, that what you want does not work at all with a default TYPO3 - there is currently no way to copy and paste pages and/or content and/or other records from one TYPO3 instance to another. And AFAIK there are no extensions either to provide you with that functionality.

Comment: Well then thanks for the answer. Weird that typo3 is considered one of the best cms, but then can not do such simple things.....

Answer (score 0):

You can export a page tree and import it into another instance.

---

On the other hand you can duplicate an instance by copying the complete database and original files.
That includes necessarily the `fileadmin/` and `uploads/` folders.
`typo3conf/` should be duplicated by deployment but might differ in the files `typo3conf/LocalConfiguration.php` and `typo3conf/AdditionalConfiguration.php` (e.g. each instance should have other databases).

Comment: I see export/import on instance 1. But on instance 2 i only see "export". So how do i import something in instance 2?

Comment: are you sure the system extension `impexp` is installed and active on your 2nd instance?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the core extension impexp to import/export content parts. There is even a context menu entry

[image: EXT:impexp]

Be aware of some drawbacks:

- if assets are exported, those are exported & imported you can hit the limit of your memory_limit
- take extra care about which uids should be used, e.g. forcing uids can lead to drawbacks

---

Of course there are other options as well like:

- create a custom extension which exports/imports the content on the fly using either something like a custom endpoint or fetching directly the DB if possible
- use 1 installation as discussed already
- if e.g. using ext:news use something like rss feeds for a poor man import/export with ext:news_importicsxml

Comment: Ok, on Backend 1 i see Export/Import. So i exported a page. Now i go to Backend 2. There i only see "export". There is no "import" button. So how do i import the already exportet page now?

Comment: there is an import in page context menu behind the "more options" entry.

Comment: in my case its not, it only appears in backend 1